# unable to scrape google results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to python and i'm learning from `automating boring stuff with python`, so currently i'm in the webscraping chapter in the book. SO, i want to just scrape the titles of the results of search results.
Here is my code -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

term = 'python'
req = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + term)
req.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
title = soup.find('div', class_ = 'r')

print(title)
```

The problem is this is always returning `None`. I even attacked the inspect element tool screen shot so that you can see the `div` and `class` name I'm using.

[image: screenshot of the inspect element page]

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get correct response from the server, specify `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'}

term = 'python'
req = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + term, headers=headers)
req.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
title = soup.find('div', class_ = 'r')

print(title.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
Welcome to Python.org www.python.org www.python.org ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked. With a little tweaking i get what ever i want now. But can you explain what this `headers` thing is?? and how does it work?

Comment: @default-303 `headers` are HTTP headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers. Google blocks requests with non-browser user agents.